# mRMR, mRMRe and ordered factors

Tags: r, feature-selection, dataset

I'm using the mRMRe package to perform mRMR in the R language.

The package only works on numeric data and ordered factors.

What are the implications for my analysis, if I coerce factors that are inherently without order, into an ordered form, using mRMR?

The [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mRMRe/index.html) gives no explanation as to why it needs ordered factors.

Thanks

Comment: In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119584/using-mrmre-for-feature-selection-with-categorical-target-variable) your question is essentially answered by the developers of `mRMRe`. Here is the quote: "The target variable can be categorical only if ordered. In the case of 2 categories, the order is arbitrary. For more categories that are not logically ordered (multicategorical classification) mRMRe is not adapted." This follows what @Simon Papillon-Cavanagh said.

Answer (score 1):

That's because mRMRe does not perform multiclass prediction. If you have more than 2 levels in your factors, mRMRe requires that you define an order for them and will assume a linear relationship between the levels. If this is not applicable to your situation you can run multiple mRMRe on "made-up" binary classes as such:

Example for 3 classes {Foo, Bar, Baz}:

- Foo vs. Bar+Baz
- Bar vs. Foo+Baz
- Baz vs. Foo+Bar

And then average all the models.

Comment: Neither the question and the answer make sense.